# php выполнение скрипта каждые сутки

Tags: php

Здравствуй ХешКод! Скажите пожалуйста как сделать такую функцию, чтобы каждые день в 0:00 по серверному времени(функция date() ) выполнялся определённый php код? Пишу конкурсы для сайта, вот и нужно выбирать победителя каждый день, а как такое сделать не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользуйтесь [cron](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)'ом